# marklogic delete > insert > cpf action on new document

Tags: transactions, xquery, marklogic

see UPDATE below!

I have the following issue: We are collecting (millions) of documents (tweets) into ML and on insert we have a cpf job that creates metadata for each document. More precise it adds a geotag based on location(if location or coordinates are present).

Now we have a database that has been collecting tweets without the geotagger active. We would like to process the stored tweets with this cpf job by deleting and re-inserting each document that does not yet have a proper metadata geotag element.
Then cpf does it's job and geotaggs the "new" document.

We have written the following code to delete and insert the documents but we get a XDMP-CONFLICTUPDATES error. I have been reading about transactions and tried several things, the ";" trick. wrapping in xdmp:eval or splitting up the delete and insert in two separate function calls from xdmp:spawn.

Still no luck.

spawn-rename.xqy

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace j = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";
declare variable $to_process external;

declare function local:document-rename(
   $old-uri as xs:string, $new-uri as xs:string)
  as empty-sequence()
{
    (:xdmp:set-transaction-mode("update"),:)
    xdmp:eval(xdmp:document-delete($old-uri)),
    (:xdmp:commit():)

    let $permissions := xdmp:document-get-permissions($old-uri)
    let $collections := xdmp:document-get-collections($old-uri)
    return xdmp:document-insert(
      $new-uri, doc($old-uri),
      if ($permissions) then $permissions
      else xdmp:default-permissions(),
      if ($collections) then $collections
      else xdmp:default-collections(),
      xdmp:document-get-quality($old-uri)
    )
};

for $d in map:keys($to_process)
let $rename := local:document-rename($d, map:get($to_process,$d))
return true()
```

and to run the job for a specific set of documents we use:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace j = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";
declare namespace dikw = 'http://www.example.com/dikw_functions.xqy';
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $foo := cts:uris((),(), cts:not-query(cts:element-query(xs:QName("j:dikwmetadata"), cts:element-query(xs:QName("j:data"), cts:and-query(())))))
let $items := cts:uri-match("/twitter/403580066367815680.json") (:any valid uri or set of uris:)

let $map := map:map()

    let $f := doc($items[1])
    let $id := $f/j:json/j:id/text()
    let $oldUri := xdmp:node-uri($f)
    let $newUri := fn:concat("/twitter/", $f/j:json/j:id/text(), ".json")
    let $put := map:put($map,$oldUri,$newUri)

    let $spawn := xdmp:spawn("/Modules/DIKW/spawn-rename-split.xqy", (xs:QName("to_process"), $map))

return ($oldUri, " - ", $newUri)
```

Question:

How can I set up the code so that it deleted the documents in the map first in a separate transaction and inserts them back later so cpf can do it's geotagging?

---

UPDATE

Ok so per grtjn his comments (thx so far!)
I try to rewrite my code like :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace j = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";

let $entries := cts:uri-match("//twitter/*")
let $entry-count := fn:count($entries)

let $transaction-size := 100 (: batch size $max :)
let $total-transactions := ceiling($entry-count div $transaction-size)

(: set total documents and total transactions so UI displays collecting :)
(: skip 84 85
let $set-total := infodev:ticket-set-total-documents($ticket-id, $entry-count)
let $set-trans := infodev:ticket-set-total-transactions($ticket-id,$total-transactions)
:)
    (: create transactions by breaking document set into maps
each maps's documents are saved to the db in their own transaction :)
let $transactions :=
    for $i at $index in 1 to $total-transactions
    let $map := map:map()
    let $start := (($i -1) *$transaction-size) + 1
    let $finish := min((($start - 1 + $transaction-size),$entry-count))
    let $put :=
        for $entry in ($entries)[$start to $finish]
        (: 96
        let $id := fn:concat(fn:string($entry/atom:id),".xml")
        :)
        let $id := fn:doc($entry)/j:json/j:id/text()
        return map:put($map,$id,$entry)
    return $map

(: the callback function for ingest 
skip 101 let $function := xdmp:function(xs:QName("feed:process-file"))
:)
let $ingestion :=
    for $transaction at $index in $transactions
    return true()
    return $ingestion (: this second return statement seems odd? :)
    (: do spawn here? :)
    (: xdmp:spawn("/modules/spawn-move.xqy", (xs:QName("to_process"), $map)) :)
```

Now I am puzzled, to get this 'working' I needed to add the last return which seems not right. Also I am trying to figure out what exactly happens, If I run the query as is it returns with a timeout error.
I would like to first understand what the transaction actually does. 
Sorry for my ignorance but seems that performing a (relatively simple) task as renaming some docs looks not that simple?

for completeness my spawn-move.qry here:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare namespace j = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";
declare variable $to_process external;


declare function local:document-move(
   $id as xs:string, $doc as xs:string)
  as empty-sequence()
{
    let $newUri := fn:concat("/twitter/", $id, ".json")
    let $ins := xdmp:document-insert($newUri,fn:doc($doc))
    let $del := xdmp:document-delete($doc) 
    return true()
};

for $d in map:keys($to_process)
let $move := local:document-move($d, map:get($to_process,$d))
return true()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are not actually renaming the documents, but just re-inserting them. The `rename` function you quote does not anticipate that situation and does a superfluous `document-delete` if `$old-uri` is identical to `$new-uri`. Add an `if` around the delete to skip it in that case. Keep everything else to preserve permissions, collections, quality, and properties. The `document-insert` function already removes pre-existing document before the actual insert. See also:

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert

You might also consider adding a bit of logic to do multiple spawns. You would want to re-insert docs in batches of 100 to 500 docs ideally, depending on hardware and forest config. There is a nice example of how to calculate 'transactions' in this infostudio collector on github (starting from line 80):

https://github.com/marklogic/infostudio-plugins/blob/master/collectors/collector-feed.xqy

You can also consider doing the geo-work inside those transactions, instead of delegating that to CPF. But if your geo-lookup involves external calls, which could for instance be slow, then stick with CPF..

HTH!

Comment: thx grtjn, i have two usecases , one indeed only reinserting existing documents but also one in which i have 500.000 docs inserted in the wrong uri starting with "//twitter/" instead of "/twitter/" so the cpf job looking at "/twitter/" missed those docs. i am looking for a way to process these. I am puzzled how to do these kind of jobs in ml in general, without running into query timeouts etc etc. With your pointer to line 80 I have a problem understanding what would be needed for me to insert and run it so that i can process 500000 docs in one go.

Comment: @hugo-koopmans Copy lines 80 upto 104, define a variable $entries containing all uris (you have $foo/$items), define a variable $entry-count with the count of entries, replace $max with 100 (that is your batch size), skip lines 84/85/96/101, edit line 97 to just put $entry as key in the map and a dummy value, and add your spawn after line 104. That way you skip calculating $newURI before spawn, but better do that in the spawned task instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your sample that you are trying to delete and write the document to the same URI in the same step.  you may get around this with xdmp:commit().  However, another solution would be to first rename the document in one batch (move them ALL out of the way) and then after that is done, move them back in batches.

Comment: thx for response,, I tried the xdmp:commit() (see in the first code I have tried that but commented in out) but that does not work, it needs a semicolon to end the transaction and you get into all kinds of issue i do not understand. I am working on your second direction but this seems sluggish to me? also the cpf process seems very slow any hints to speed up cpf?

Comment: http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2013/06/21/introduction-to-multi-statement-transactions/ might help you understand `xdmp:commit` and the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have your CPF pipelines configured to handle updates like creates (this is the default configuration) then just reinserting the document is enough:

xdmp:document-insert($d, doc($d))